# KMDF driver process protection

Tags: process, driver, kmdf

I am new to driver development, I developed a driver that successfully protects my service process from being interrupted like kill from task manager or process explorer. But, when i run command "taskkill /f /im ServiceProcess.exe" as administrator, it kills the service process. But task manager or process explorer (as admin) gives "access is denied" message. How is this possible?